Can Salesforce MobilePush SDK detect when a user opts out of push notifications at the device level?
I'm using SFMC integrated with my mobile app via MobilePush SDK. I want to know if the SDK can automatically detect when a user disables push notifications on their device (at the OS level, in system settings) and report this change back to SFMC.
Specifically:
Does MobilePush SDK provide a way to know when push notifications have been disabled by the user on their device?
If a user disables notifications, does the SDK update SFMC with an "opt-out" status for that user?
Are there any best practices or recommended methods to handle this scenario?
Any guidance on how to configure or handle this would be greatly appreciated!

According to the Opt-Outs docs,

If a contact deletes your app or disables notifications for your app on their device, they are opted out.

This is also mentioned in the MobilePush FAQs which provides a bit more context around when a user is prompted to Opt-In to notifications.

Does it mean that opt out at operating system level don't notitify SFMC?  "On iOS, disabling push notifications doesn’t unregister the device. Instead, push notification payloads are received but aren’t delivered. The device doesn’t appear in APNs feedback as a result of disabling push notifications."?
